# Rails Carrierwave add more files undefined method `identifier'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to implement the add more files and remove a single file with the `carrierwave gem`. I've followed the instructions which I found [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Add-more-files-and-remove-single-file-when-using-default-multiple-file-uploads-feature). But when I try to add more files the old ones become `NUL` and get deleted for some reason. No error appear but if I take look at the console I get this:

```
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "items" SET "images" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "items"."id" = $3  [["images", "{NULL,NULL,image5.jpg,image6.jpg}"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-18 07:58:52.685554"], ["id", 85]] (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

Also when I try to remove a file nothing happens. No error appears and the file still remains as is, but if I take look at the console I'm getting this:

```
 SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "items" SET "images" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "items"."id" = $3  [["images", "{NULL,NULL,image5.jpg,image6.jpg}"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-18 08:00:29.641571"], ["id", 85]] (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

I have no idea why this is happening and I have been trying to solve this for a while now, so any help on how to make this work would be very much appreciated.

Here is the setup I have:

I added this column to the item model:

```
add_column :items, :images, :string, array: true, default: []
```

These are the routes I have:

```
match 'store/item/:id'=> 'attachments#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :remove_item_image
post "store/item/:id"=> "attachments#create", :as => :create_item_image
```

The controller:

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_item

def create
  add_more_images(images_params[:images])
  flash[:error] = "Failed uploading images" unless @item.save
  redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
end

def destroy
  remove_image_at_index(params[:id].to_i)
  flash[:error] = "Failed deleting image" unless @item.save
  redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
end

private

def set_item
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end

def add_more_images(new_images)
  images = @item.images
  images += new_images
  @item.images = images
end

def remove_image_at_index(index)
  remain_images = @item.images # copy the array
  deleted_image = remain_images.delete_at(index) # delete the target image
  deleted_image.try(:remove!) # delete image from S3
  @item.images = remain_images # re-assign back
end

def images_params
  params.require(:item).permit({images: []}) # allow nested params as array
end
end
```

This is the view where I loop through the images and add the remove link:

```
<% @item.images.each_with_index do |img, index| #grab the index %>
<%= image_tag(img.url(:mini)) %>
<%= link_to "Remove", remove_item_image_path(@item, index: index), data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this image?" }, :method => :delete %>
 <% end %>
```

This is the form to add more images:

```
<%= form_for @item, url: create_item_image_path(@item), method: :post , :html => {:id => "form", :multipart => true } do |f| %>
 <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
 <%= f.submit 'Add more files' %>
 <% end %>
```

**Update 1**

When I try to add a local image manually from `rails console` I do this:

```
@item = Item.find(85)
@item.images << [File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/no-image.jpg", 'rb')]
```

The new local images is being added to the array, but when I do this `@item.save` I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `identifier' for #<Array:0x007fd2536ccd98>
    from (irb):4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding an array to the @item.images association, it expects a File and tries to call `identifier` on it. Set only the file:

```
@item.images << File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/no-image.jpg", 'rb')
```

If you want to add multiple images at once you can do that on a loop or maybe the `@image.images` object has some method to add multiple images (I can't find it on the docs, but I guess there's one). On the link you provided it does:

```
images += new_images
```